# Cloud Services for Android Phones

Tags: cloud

I own an RugGear 702 Android phone. All of my apps get downloaded to my phone storage and not the SD card,  even when I select the SD card option form the phone settings. Is it possible to somehow treat apps like cloud services, where all the tasks of applications (or apps) downloading, executing apps, messaging (and other communication services) can be executed from the cloud?

Answer (score 0):

You could install the Android emulator on a server and remote into it.  I also seem to recall the ability to test apps from the Amazon Appstore on their website but I can't find that at the moment.

Android apps aren't built on X-Windowing or anything like that, though, so there's no efficient way to locally display a remote app.  VNC/RDP/etc. is going to be pretty data-intensive, probably slow, and difficult to navigate and control input.